# Rails - query db with "namespaced" URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model like `Trips( id:integer, from: string, to: string, date: date)`.

How can I set my routes and trips_controller in order to be able to query my DB just getting URLs like `root_path/trips/:from/:to/:date` ?

Comment: Can you show us an example of that url?

Comment: something like root_path/trips/Boston/Chicago/2016-07-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this into your routes file `config/routes.rb`:

```
get 'trips/:from/:to/:date', action: 'index', controller: 'trips'
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  # You can use whatever action instead of 'index'
  def index
    from = params[:from]
    to = params[:to]
    date = params[:date] # You can even parse this with Date.parse(params[:date])

    # Do whatever you want with those values
  end
end
```

Comment: awesome, it works :) actually, it was easier than expected!